# XSD lowercase enumeration, translated to jaxb object and then to json string, became UPPERCASE

Tags: java, json, xsd, jaxb, jackson

I have an XSD file with enumeration in lower case e.g.

```
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="oneTwo"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="threeFour"/>
        ...`
```

When I translate it to java classes using jaxb, I'm getting:

```
public enum MyType{

    @XmlEnumValue("oneTwo")
    ONE_TWO("oneTwo"),
    @XmlEnumValue("threeFour")
    THREE_FOUR("threeFour"),

    private final String value;
    ...`
```

I'm using jackson in order to marshal/unmarshal the jaxb objects, and getting this enums as in the ONE_TWO form, while I need these enums in their original (from XSD) form.

How can I do that?

Is there any way to change the jaxb naming convention? or alternatively, modify json marshaling so it will use the enum "value" method instead the enum name?

Thanks!

Comment: Appendix D.3 of JAXB 2.1 specs says that the conversion to uppercase _must_ be done, hence you probably should hope that json marshaling offers something.