# Is it possible to generate low case java enum constants using JAXB?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

Following part of xsd schema:

```
    <xs:simpleType name="Component">
    <xs:enumeration value="Common"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

creates java enum with one constant - `Component.COMMON`. Is it possible to generate enum with low case constant (e.g. Component.common) using JAXB?

Comment: Constants should be in UPPER_CASE. Why do you want them to be lower case?

Comment: Please don't do this. Stick to the java naming conventions.

Comment: I agree that it looks strange. But this enum constant is used as a field during marshalling but client app waits for low case string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSD lowercase enumeration, translated to jaxb object and then to json string, became UPPERCASE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918762/xsd-lowercase-enumeration-translated-to-jaxb-object-and-then-to-json-string-be)

Comment: The text that a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation marshals to XML will match what is in the XML schema, is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: There are valid reasons for allowing non uppercase enum names, the most important being mapping enum values to property names in property files. Furthermore, the equation of a Java enum to a simple constant seems to me overly simplistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it should be based on the same technique that achieves type safe enumerations (e.g. integer values).

[This link](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Iona/artix/5.5/jaxws_pguide/JAXWSCustomTypeMappingEnum.html) should help.

In your case, it should look as this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Component" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"> 
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Common">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="common" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>                
        </xs:enumeration>           
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And you get this:

```
@XmlType(name = "Component")
@XmlEnum
public enum Component {

    @XmlEnumValue("Common")
    common("Common");
    private final String value;

    Component(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static Component fromValue(String v) {
        for (Component c: Component.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```